# Create columns with data using CASE statement when a condition is met

Tags: oracle

I need help populating 'DAYTIME' values for the columns created using CASE statements below with oracle.

My Script

```
WITH your_query
        AS (SELECT SLMCU AS "BUSINESSUNIT",
                   SLDOCO AS "ORDERNO",
                   SLDCTO AS "ORDERTYPE",
                   SLAN8 AS "CUSTOMERNO",
                   ABALPH AS "CUSTOMERNAME",
                   SLLITM AS "ITEMNO",
                   SLDSC1 AS "DESCRIPTION",
                   SLDSC2 AS "DESCRIPTION2",
                   SLLTTR AS "LAST STATUS",
                   SLNXTR AS "NEXT STATUS",
                   CASE SLTRDJ
                      WHEN 0 THEN TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (1 + 1900000), 'YYYYDDD')
                      ELSE TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (SLTRDJ + 1900000), 'YYYYDDD')
                   END
                      AS "ORDER DATE",
                   CASE SLADDJ
                      WHEN 0 THEN TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (1 + 1900000), 'YYYYDDD')
                      ELSE TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (SLADDJ + 1900000), 'YYYYDDD')
                   END
                      AS "SHIPPED DATE",
                   SLTDAY AS "DAYTIME",
                   SLUORG / 10000 AS "ORDER QUANTITY",
                   SLSOQS / 10000 AS "SHIPPED QUANTITY"
              FROM PRODDTA.F42199 INNER JOIN PRODDTA.F0101 ON SLAN8 = ABAN8
             WHERE SLTRDJ = 119327 AND SLLNID = 1000 AND ROWNUM <= 200)
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               CASE
                  WHEN "NEXT STATUS" = 540 THEN "DAYTIME" 
                  END
                  AS time_of_day,
               CASE
                  WHEN "NEXT STATUS" = 580
                  THEN
                     "DAYTIME"
               END
                  AS shipped_time
          FROM (SELECT q.*
                  FROM your_query q) t
         WHERE "NEXT STATUS" IN (540, 580, 620))
 WHERE "NEXT STATUS" = 620
```

Result

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the 'DAYTIME' value of every row returned by my inner query when 'NEXT STATUS' condition is met but my query is failing, judging from the null values in 'time_of_day'  and 'shipped_time' columns.

Desired Output

[image]

EDIT: Data Model

ORDER_NO    ORDER_TYPE  CUSTOMER_NO CUSTOMER_NAME   LAST_ STATUS    NEXT_ STATUS    ORDER_ DATE SHIPPED_DATE    DAYTIME ORDER_ QTY  SHIPPED_ QTY
19440263    SO  295042  MERU DEPOT  520 540 12/5/2019   1/1/1900    140556  8   8
19440263    SO  295042  MERU DEPOT  540 580 12/5/2019   12/5/2019   140745  8   8
19440263    SO  295042  MERU DEPOT  580 582 12/5/2019   12/5/2019   140822  8   8
19440263    SO  295042  MERU DEPOT  582 620 12/5/2019   12/5/2019   140837  8   8
19440263    SO  295042  MERU DEPOT  620 999 12/5/2019   12/5/2019   90333   8   8

19440270    SO  295042  MERU DEPOT  520 540 12/5/2019   1/1/1900    144529  2   2
19440270    SO  295042  MERU DEPOT  540 580 12/5/2019   12/5/2019   144725  2   2
19440270    SO  295042  MERU DEPOT  580 582 12/5/2019   12/5/2019   144757  2   2
19440270    SO  295042  MERU DEPOT  582 620 12/5/2019   12/5/2019   144813  2   2
19440270    SO  295042  MERU DEPOT  620 999 12/5/2019   12/5/2019   90336   2   2

19562535    ST  295046  NAKURU DEPOT    520 540 12/5/2019   1/1/1900    202705  11  11
19562535    ST  295046  NAKURU DEPOT    540 560 12/5/2019   1/1/1900    203058  11  11
19562535    ST  295046  NAKURU DEPOT    560 580 12/5/2019   12/5/2019   233630  11  11
19562535    ST  295046  NAKURU DEPOT    580 582 12/5/2019   12/5/2019   234505  11  11
19562535    ST  295046  NAKURU DEPOT    582 620 12/5/2019   12/5/2019   234627  11  11

19759237    SV  200977  D HOLDINGS LTD                  520 540 12/5/2019   1/1/1900    134200  12  12
19759237    SV  200977  D HOLDINGS LTD                  540 560 12/5/2019   1/1/1900    134800  12  12
19759237    SV  200977  D HOLDINGS LTD                  560 580 12/5/2019   12/5/2019   160704  12  12
19759237    SV  200977  D HOLDINGS LTD                  580 582 12/5/2019   12/5/2019   160911  12  12
19759237    SV  200977  D HOLDINGS LTD                  582 620 12/5/2019   12/5/2019   161034  12  12
19759237    SV  200977  D HOLDINGS LTD                  620 999 12/5/2019   12/5/2019   90340   12  12

19759240    SV  200007  Naivasha Gen                520 540 12/5/2019   1/1/1900    155110  11  11
19759240    SV  200007  Naivasha Gen                540 560 12/5/2019   1/1/1900    155506  11  11
19759240    SV  200007  Naivasha Gen                560 580 12/5/2019   12/5/2019   173205  11  11
19759240    SV  200007  Naivasha Gen                580 582 12/5/2019   12/5/2019   173424  11  11
19759240    SV  200007  Naivasha Gen                582 620 12/5/2019   12/5/2019   173526  11  11
19759240    SV  200007  Naivasha Gen                620 999 12/5/2019   12/5/2019   90346   11  11

Comment: Your outer where condition restricts the records which have dates calculated by case condition

Comment: The "SELECT t.*" sub query is only retrieving records with NEXT STATUS of 540,580 and 620. Only the first two of those are getting the SHIPPED_TIME and TIME_OF_DAY set via the CASE. Your outer query is then only returning rows with NEXT STATUS of 620 - which have not had that value set using the CASE.

Comment: So ultimately, you will find the dates when you will change your outer query from `WHERE "NEXT STATUS" = 620` to `WHERE "NEXT STATUS" = 540`

Comment: @BriteSponge Using an example, kindly show me how to rewrite my query so that  SHIPPED_TIME and TIME_OF_DAY columns are shown on rows with NEXT STATUS of 620, which is what i intended to achieve in the first place.

Comment: @Tejash final result should only show rows with NEXT STATUS of 620 but with SHIPPED_TIME and TIME_OF_DAY columns included at the end.

Comment: Your query is difficult to read.  Multi-word aliases surrounded by quotes make everything confusing.  Additionally, while you put table aliases in, you don't use them when specifying column names. There is no reason to use a WITH clause here.  Just modify the original query so that it has the columns you are looking for.  Lastly, @Tejash is right, all of you columns will be NULL as you are are only pulling rows with a value of 620.  You omitted all of the 540 and 580 rows which had something in those two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your original query and your comments you seem to want to output all the columns from the sub-query with two derived columns; TIME_OF_DAY and SHIPPED.
In your query both those columns contained the DAYTIME value from the sub-query.
Therefore the following, much simpler query should satisfy those requirements. You also only wanted records with a NEXT TATUS of 620 (540 and 580 don't seem to be at all relevant).

```
WITH your_query
        AS (...your original sub-query...)
SELECT q.*,
       "DAYTIME" AS time_of_day,
       "DAYTIME" AS shipped_time
  FROM your_query q
 WHERE "NEXT STATUS" = 620
```

EDIT:
So this is a very different requirement to what it originally appeared you wanted.
This query breaks out the 3 slnxtr values into their own sub-query and then joins them.
Without knowing your datamodel/data properly I can't be sure of the join conditions but conceptually this should be the simplest.
There are probably other ways using analytic functions but again, without knowing your status transition rules I don't want to speculate.

```
WITH row_620
        AS (SELECT SLMCU AS "BUSINESSUNIT",
                   SLDOCO AS "ORDERNO",
                   SLDCTO AS "ORDERTYPE",
                   SLAN8 AS "CUSTOMERNO",
                   ABALPH AS "CUSTOMERNAME",
                   SLLITM AS "ITEMNO",
                   SLDSC1 AS "DESCRIPTION",
                   SLDSC2 AS "DESCRIPTION2",
                   SLLTTR AS "LAST STATUS",
                   SLNXTR AS "NEXT STATUS",
                   CASE SLTRDJ
                      WHEN 0 THEN TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (1 + 1900000), 'YYYYDDD')
                      ELSE TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (SLTRDJ + 1900000), 'YYYYDDD')
                   END AS "ORDER DATE",
                   CASE SLADDJ
                      WHEN 0 THEN TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (1 + 1900000), 'YYYYDDD')
                      ELSE TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (SLADDJ + 1900000), 'YYYYDDD')
                   END AS "SHIPPED DATE",
                   SLTDAY AS "DAYTIME",
                   SLUORG / 10000 AS "ORDER QUANTITY",
                   SLSOQS / 10000 AS "SHIPPED QUANTITY"
              FROM PRODDTA.F42199 INNER JOIN PRODDTA.F0101 ON SLAN8 = ABAN8
             WHERE SLTRDJ = 119327 AND SLLNID = 1000 AND ROWNUM <= 200
               AND SLNXTR = 620)
      row_540
        AS (SELECT sldoco, sltday     
              FROM proddta.f42199
                   INNER JOIN PRODDTA.F0101 ON SLAN8 = ABAN8
             WHERE SLTRDJ = 119327 AND SLLNID = 1000
               AND SLNXTR = 540)
      row_580
        AS (SELECT sldoco, sltday     
              FROM proddta.f42199
                   INNER JOIN PRODDTA.F0101 ON SLAN8 = ABAN8
             WHERE SLTRDJ = 119327 AND SLLNID = 1000
               AND SLNXTR = 580)
SELECT t.*,
       b.sltday time_of_day,
       c.sltday shipped_time
  FROM row_640 a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       row_540 b ON a.sldoco = b.sldoco
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       row_580 c ON a.sldoco = c.sldoco
```

Comment: I have added an image showing what my query should return under Desired Output.

Comment: my query should return orders with NEXT STATUS = 620 but also with DAYTIME values of NEXT STATUS = 540 & 580 in derived TIME_OF_DAY and SHIPPED_TIME columns

Comment: thank you for the update, although the new query is now executing for more than an hour cause proddta.f42199 has over 2 million rows. Based on your edited query, is there a way i can rewrite it to obtain  b.sltday time_of_day and c.sltday shipped_time from what row_620 table has returned.

Comment: the data model is included.